# Does bluemix SSO support Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

Does Bluemix SSO support securing Angular 2.0 Routes? So I have a NodeJS app that I have secured with Bluemix SSO, following all the samples puting the code into app.js. However, With angular 2.0 there is no app.js. How can you place the code for SSO to secure your angular application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Bluemix Single Sign On Service only supports Node.js and JAVA(Liberty) application.

If you wish support for another type of application then you will need to open an Enhancement Request, and the Product Management will review.

Instructions on how to open an Enhancement Request can be found in the following link

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/257231/how-can-i-submit-a-request-for-enhancement-rfe-for-1.html